# Python Linear Regression input values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Excel sheet with 2 colums and 1000 rows.
I want to give this as inputs to my Linear Regression Fit command using the sklearn.
/
when I want to create a dataframe using panda how can I give the inputs?
like `df_x=pd.dataFrame(...)`

I used without dataframe sucessfully as:

```
npMatrix=np.matrix(raw_data)
X,Y=npMatrix[:,1],npMatrix[:,2]

md1=LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
```

Can you help with me Pandas how to access the rows?

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(...)`, `arr = df.as_matrix()`

Comment: how can I get x and y from the pd...did not get can u please give more info

Comment: if you need it as numpy array then `arr = df.as_matrix()` and `X = arr[:,0]`, `Y = arra[:,1]` or `X = df[0].as_matrix()` , `Y = df[1].as_matrix()`

Comment: Thanks Numpy i am able to do as mentioned in the question. I want to get it as a dataframe

Comment: If you need as dataframe then `X = df[0]`  and `Y = df[1]`. If your columns have names (ie. `"column1"`, `"column2"`) then `X = df["column1"]`  and `Y = df["column2"]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert a pandas dataframe to a numpy array by `np.array()`

This is discussed here: [Quora: How does python-pandas go along with scikit-learn library?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-python-pandas-go-along-with-scikit-learn-library-Has-anyone-doing-data-analysis-using-pandas-and-then-then-fit-models-using-scikit-learn)

The example, by Muktabh Mayank, is copied below:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> from numpy import *
>>> new_df = DataFrame(array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,8,10,11],[16,45,67,88]]))
>>> new_df.index= ["A1","A2","A3","A4"]
>>> new_df.columns= ["X1","X2","X3","X4"]
>>> new_df
X1  X2  X3  X4
A1   1   2   3   4
A2   5   6   7   8
A3   9   8  10  11
A4  16  45  67  88
>>> array(new_df)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
   [ 9,  8, 10, 11],
   [16, 45, 67, 88]], dtype=int64)
>>>
```

And btw, people are actually working on bridging sklearn and pandas: [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can read excel

```
df = pd.read_excel(...)
```

You can single column using column number

```
X = df[0] 
Y = df[1]
```

If columns have names ie. `"column1"`, `"column2"`

```
X = df["column1"] 
Y = df["column2"]
```

But it gives single column as `Series`.
If you need single column as `DataFrame` then use list of columns

```
X = df[ [0] ]
Y = df[ [1] ]
```

More: [How to get column by number in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194149/1832058)