# Filter column maximum value and respective row value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I want to filter max value from 7th column and respective row (date and time)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
a = pd.read_html("D:\\abcd\New folder\PRTG Report AIRTEL-5PM to 9 PM 64-32768-32723.html", flavor='bs4',header=None)
df0=a[0]
df1=a[1]
df2=a[2][https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbjT.png][1]
df3=a[3]
df=df0.append([df1,df2,df3])
df[df != 'Average'].iloc[:,[1,7]].dropna()
```

[image: Open image]

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly what you would like to obtain. Could you describe your problem and present a minimal example of input and expected output?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbjT.png

Comment: please open above image this is the out put im getting from this I want filter the 7 th column maximum value and its respective date and time from 1st coloumn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum value of a column and return the corresponding row values using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan)

Comment: but I don't have headers that's why mi struck I already seen this post

Comment: You can combine it together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193850/how-to-get-column-by-number-in-pandas - `df.iloc[:,7]`

Answer (score 1):

First obtain the index for maximum value in column `7` by using [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and then use that index to get the row:

```
index_for_max_7 = df.iloc[:,7].idxmax()
df.iloc[index_for_max_7]
```

Comment: I added the link for doc because it helped me with your answer. +1