# How to access particular elements of a dataframe in Pandas. Gives error

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pyodbc

I have a dataframe `df_params`. It contains parameters for the stored procedure.

```
   PurchaseOrderID   OrderDate SupplierReference     DF_Name
0                1  2013-01-01          B2084020  dataframe1
1                2  2013-01-01            293092  dataframe2
2                3  2013-01-01          08803922  dataframe3
3                4  2013-01-01         BC0280982  dataframe4
4                5  2013-01-01         ML0300202  dataframe5
```

I simply want to access the elements of the dataframe in a loop:

```
for i in range(len(df_params)):
    print(df_params[i][0])
```

But it gives me an error without really explanation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:my\path\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test3.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(df_params[i][0])
  File "C:\Users\my\path\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\my\path\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\my\path>
```

The goal is to supply value to the stored procedure:

```
for i in range(len(df_params)):
    query = "EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder " + df_params[i][0] + "," + str(df_params[i][1]) + "," + df_params[i][2])
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

**desired outcome from print(query):**

```
EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder 1, '2013-01-01', 'B2084020'
EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder 2, '2013-01-01', '293092'
EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder 3, '2013-01-01', '08803922'
EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder 4, '2013-01-01', 'BC0280982'
EXEC Purchasing.GetPurchaseOrder 5, '2013-01-01', 'ML0300202'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get column by number in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193850/how-to-get-column-by-number-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame`s don't behave exactly like `numpy.ndarray`s. There are basically three options:

**option 1: iterrows-method:**
You can iterate over rows of a pandas.dataframe by

```py
for idx, row in df_params.iterrows():
    print(row['PurchaseOrderID'])
```

This is a particularly readable way, so personally I prefer this

**option 2: indexing:**
if you want to index pandas.dataframe just like an numpy.ndarray object, go with the method [`.iat[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)

```py
for i in range(len(df_params)):
    print(df_params.iat[i, 0])
```

This actually indexes all elements and *ignores the index of the dataframe!* So assuming that you have a different index (in the extreme some strings or a table with a `pandas.DataTimeIndex`) this still works... just as if you would have done a `df_params.to_numpy()[i, 0]`.
*Note:* There exists a similar function that uses the column name: [`.at[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

There is a second way to index a `pandas.DataFrame` object and it is just a little safer with regard to columns:[`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) It takes an *index* and column name(s)

```py
for idx in df_params.index:
    print(df_params.iloc[idx, 'PurchaseOrderID'])
```

**option 3: slicing a pandas.Series object:**
Every column in a `pandas.DataFrame` is a `pandas.Series` object, which you can index similar (you actually *index* the series as described above) to a `numpy.ndarray`:

```py
col = df_params['PurchaseOrderID']
for idx in col.index:
    print(col[idx])
```

**So what went wrong in your case?**
The double indexing is almost the same as the last example **but** it calls calls [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) under the hood and thus expects a *column name* and not a number (that would have been the method `.iloc[]`. **And** it is expecting to see the column first and then the row.
So if you really want, you could go like this:

```py
for i in range(len(df_params)):
    print(df_params.iloc[0][i])
```

**but** this only works because *your `pandas.DataFrame` has continuous numeric indices starting from 0!* So please don't do this and use the actual indices of your table (actually use one of the options above and not the last one ;) )

Answer (score 0):

On data frame there are better ways to access values, you can use lambda.
with lambda will have an access to any row.

```
df.apply(lambda row : print(row['DF_Name']))
```

now the variable 'row' is each row on the dataframe, and you can access to each properties on the row.